# What will happen if commit() method called on consumer running in auto commit mode?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

I'm calling the `consumer.commit()` method on each message of consumer running in auto.commit=True mode. When I tried it locally it worked without any data loss or data duplication.

What are the effects the `commit()` method can give to the consumer?

```py
class KafkaConsumer(object):
    def __init__(self, topics: list[str], **kwargs: Any):
        config = {
            **kwargs,
        }
        self.consumer = DeserializingConsumer(config)
        self.consumer.subscribe(topics=topics)

    def consume(self, poll_timeout_secs: float = 1.0):
        while True:
            msg = self.consumer.poll(timeout=poll_timeout_secs)
            if msg is None:
                continue
            if msg.error():
                raise KafkaException(msg.error())
            else:
                yield msg

kafka_consumer = KafkaConsumer(topics=topics, **kwargs) # passed "enable.auto.commit":True

for message in kafka_consumer.consume():
    event = message.value()
    logger.info(f"message {event}")
    kafka_consumer.commit() # what will be the effect of calling this?
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer any idea on this?

Comment: AFAIK, it should just commit the current offset and move on